# Strpos not working correctly

Tags: php, strpos

Currently I am having a bunch of issues filtering it so that only post which include the string `http://www.example.com/?dl_name=` go through.

The first `if` statement works flawlessly but the second one returns every post that I am scraping even the ones that don't have the url included above what am I doing wrong?

```
$url = ''.$element->href;
$html2 = file_get_html($url);
$title = $html2->find('.single-style1-title h1',0);
$s = $title->plaintext;
$str2 = explode ("MUSIC:", $s);
print '<br>';
$date = $html2->find('strong > a',0);
$n = $date->href;
$str = explode ("http://www.example.com/?dl_name=", $n);
if (strpos($title->plaintext,"VIDEO:")===FALSE) { 
    if (strpos($n,'http://www.example.com/?dl_name=') !== true) {   
        $image = $html2->find('.thumb-wrap img',0);
        //$date = $html2->find('strong > a',0);
        //$n = $date->href;
        print '<br><br>';
        echo $url;
        print '<br>';
        print htmlspecialchars_decode($image->src);
        print '<br>';
        print $str2[1];
        print '<br>';
        print $str[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: ***My use of*** strpos is not working correctly - there, fixed that for you :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
if (strpos($n,'http://www.example.com/?dl_name=') !== true)
```

`strpos` never returns `true`. Quote [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

Comment: What can I do to get the ouput I am looking for without using `strpos`?

Comment: @JohnDoe If you need to ensure there is _no_ match in string, then just invert your condition: `if (strpos(...) === false)`. If you need the opposite, then use `if (strpos(...) !== false)`.

Comment: when I do this, it returns ONLY the result I don't want it to return, I need everything except the content being displayed when we set `true` to `false` this is the issue..

Comment: You could even do `(!!strpos(...))`.. [**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#BGWeNSnoP)

Comment: @JohnDoe use the case **in-sensitive** version -> `if (stripos($n,'http://www.example.com/?dl_name=') !== FALSE) {..`

Comment: @Darren the first thing you posted was actually improvement it pointed out which post did not include the link I was looking for but it still included every `print` displayed for every other post when I am trying to get it to completely not scrape that element at all if said title portion is not set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
strpos($n,'http://www.example.com/?dl_name=') !== true
```

strpos never returns `true`, only `FALSE` if it is not present, or the first position it occurs. You said that you want strings which contain `"http://www.example.com/?dl_name="` right?

Try change it to `strpos($n,'http://www.example.com/?dl_name=') !== FALSE` and see what happens.

Comment: It gives the same output as it does with `true` being set I have been tinkering with this for around 2 hours now with no luck thus far.